# Opening a new jframe, and show the specified jpanel in that jframe

Tags: java, netbeans

```
Toevoegen frame = new Toevoegen();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

this opens the new frame for me, but is there a way of showing a specified jpanel, because in that jframe there is a tabbedpane, and i want to show the (specified) tab

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(tabIndex);
```

Comment: If his answer helped, please click the the check button just below the downvote.